# How to send a captured packet saved as text with Python

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, scapy, pcap, tcpdump

I captured packets on individual text files with tcpdump, I want to send back the captured packets, first I extracted the IP and Port, but I have not been able to send the packet.

This is my code:

```
def client():
    packet = open("packet3.txt", "r") 
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(10)
    sock.connect(("192.168.128.1", 80))
    while True:
        try:
            sock.send("packet")
            sleep(1)
            reply = sock.recv(131072)
            if not reply:
                break
                print "recvd: ", reply
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "bye"
            break
    sock.close()
    return

client()
```

I get this error:

```
reply = sock.recv(131072)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should edit your question with [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a guide.